# No connection could be made using mysql_* API

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

I tried to connect mysql database.but am getting the following error.

> **Warning:** `mysql_connect()`: [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively (trying to connect via `tcp://localhost:3306`) in `test.php` on line **5**
>
> **Warning**: `mysql_connect():` No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. in test.php on line **5** Warning: `mysql_close()` expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in `test.php` on line **15**

**test.php:**

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect(localhost, dbuser, dbpass);
if (!$link) {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: hopefully there is no such thing as MTSQI

Comment: Is `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it` not very clear?

Comment: That is the warning am getting when i run the test.php file

Comment: The code you have written is trying to open a connection to MySQL on the `localhost` ie the same machine that the PHP is running on ... do you have MySQL installed and running ? or are you trying to connect to a different MySQL server ?

Comment: What is your OS? Did you change/set any firewall settings?

Answer (score 8):

This happened to us when running a PHP & MySQL on IIS7 in Windows Server 2008 in VirtualBox. It turns out that the Windows hosts file didn't have an IPv4 entry for localhost (127.0.0.1) so the route to MySQL on localhost was not found.

We added the following to the hosts file which resolved it:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost # Additional IPv4 entry
::1             localhost # Existing IPv6 localhost entry
```

Reference: [A brief description of PHP/MySQL Localhost via IPv4 & IPv6](http://bobstrand.com/totm/2010/04/hey-dude-wheres-my-localhost/)

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL server isn't running, or you have a firewall blocking port 3306.

This error message means the system did not accept the TCP connection request.

Comment: Oh thank you justin.But what can be done for this type of error.

Comment: @jsk answer ManseUK's questions above.

Answer (score 1):

In my.ini find string:

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

Change from localhost to network IP.

Comment: bind-address    = 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 1):

Got the same message trying to connect to 'localhost' by mistake (on a Windows server). After fixing the connection string to the correct (remote) server the error disappeared.