# mysql_connect(): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: php, mysql

I have this problem when I am trying to run my PHP MySQL script. When I try to run my .php file this is what I get.

```
mysql_connect(): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

This is code for dbconnect.php:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root");
mysql_select_db("users");
?>
```

I tried to use this format before but I don't know what seems to be the problem with this code.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have mysql running

Comment: you forgot third parameter of mysql_connect. i.e. passowrd

Comment: What type of host is this? OS?

Comment: @WayneWhitty > I am using Windows 7 as an OS.

Comment: check here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19517566/connecting-to-mysql-in-xampp-without-password  and http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/solved-only-connect-to-mysql-as-root-userno-password/      it has soln what you need

Comment: Try 

`$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("users", $con);`

Answer (score 8):

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

means that no error in your code , but either you have firewall which blocks your connection or your system is listening in different PORT.

to do: 1-verify your connecting port default is 3306.

2-try connect with use "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost" this maybe it listening on "127.0.0.1".

3-It could also go wrong if the other end is listening on UDP, not TCP.

4- verify your firewall connection if its permitted.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. But I did not put any password for my DB. What should I put as a syntax for that?

Comment: i dont know what password is by default , but you can go to phpmyadmin and set new password for specified user. maybe is empty password. try use `""` ;  , but you keep in mind to use a password.

Comment: Usually user access permission issues trigger a different error. Something like "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using     
password: NO) "

Comment: I put on a password, but when I tried to refresh the localhost/phpmyadmin it looks like it crashed, so I have to reinstall it.

Comment: Is it windows? What version is the mysql server? Have you tried replacing localhost with 127.0.0.1? Is the port correct? Default is 3306

Comment: Yeah I have tried that. But when I posted a password for my DB. I got this message `#2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.`

Comment: 4-check your firewall connection , 5-try uninstall and install your server. 6- post what you using , (windows, localhost server, mysql version, ...)

Comment: @echo_Me you should get rid of your answer (the upper part), it is not helpful and has many upvotes..

Comment: @user3335903 please take a look at  my answer, it is not the solution but it seems the better way to address the issue.

Comment: I answered my question. Please refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21988792/2002-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused)

Comment: this solution is same i told you to check and set your password,

Comment: @enapupe it really helpful the upper part as he forgot to make password in his connection and its wrong.

Comment: Is there something wrong if I try to help others as well? By answering my own question? I don't see anything wrong with that.

Comment: answer it here , not create other question with same issue . this question is discussed here.

Comment: Does it have the same issue? If yes, my apologies I posted in another question.

Answer (score 6):

The subject response is NOT coming from MySQL server, but from the client itself.
It could not connect to the server because the MACHINE (not the server) refused it, so, it was more likely to be a network issue or some other thing.

Try connecting to 127.0.0.1. Also check the port you are connecting to and which port is mysql running. Check for firewalls blocking connections. Are you sure is MySQL Server running?

This answer may have additional info: [No connection could be made using mysql_* API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388962/php-mysqlno-connection-could-be-made)

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your mysql Service is running, by going to check in Services:
in Search type: Services -> check mysql, start service if it's not running.

Answer (score 1):

Well sometimes even using localhost without any port number can help.
E.g.

```
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");//for no password
```

Comment: This answer is not related to the problem

Answer (score 1):

Just check your Server Port and do connection as follows:

- If your port no. is 3308:
- Username = root,
- Password = "",
- database name = form (OPTIONAL),
- then,

  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost:3308","root","","form");

Answer (score 0):

It should be `mysql_connect("localhost","root" ,"your password");`

If no password, then leave it blank like this: `mysql_connect("localhost","root" ,"");`

**NOTE:** Use Mysqli instead of MySql because mysql is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The issue was that  MySql was not running on Xampp so I had to run it for everything to work.

So kindly ensure MySql is running on your localhost. Go to Xampp [or other localhost] control panel and click start/run under Mysql ].

Answer (score 0):

Okay I fixed this error! there is no coding mistakes your SQL connection. it's caused by port# for SQL. go to your XAmp or wamp tools from active drop down and select "use a port other than 'given #' ". Then enter 3306 there. It will fix the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Changing "mysql://username:password@/databasename" to "mysql://username:password@localhost/databasename" fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

There are two database engines - MySQL DB and Maria DB. In your system, the database engine which is working may not over the default port. So check the active database engine and its port. Connect the database using:

`mysqli_connect(host, username, password, dbname, port, socket)`

for example:

`mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "dbname", "3307")`

The port number is available in the `my.ini` file or in the status menu of wampserver.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error. I was using Xampp only for web server and MySQL8.0 running on local port (not the one included in Xampp). I found out that MySQL was not running.

On Windows.

Go to Services (search for services in Cortana) and check MySQL if it is running. In my case it was set to manual, right click on it-> go to properties set startup type to automatic.

Hope error will resolve it by then.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I just stop MYSQL80 service and then I started my **xampp** mysql and it works for my case

Answer (score 0):

`No Default DBMS Default DBMS : none`
This means that none of the database managers (`MariaDB` and/or `MySQL`) use port `3306`, and it is therefore imperative to specify the port number in connection requests since this is not the default port `3306`.
It is then essential that you choose which DBMS you want to use by default; to do this, use the built-in tools (`Right-click -> Tools`) to assign port `3306` (Use a port other than xxxx) to the DBMS (`MariaDB` or `MySQL`) you want to set as default.

Answer (score -2):

It looks like you forgot to add your password to your connection. Also, you should not use mysql connect anymore as it is officially **depreciated**. Use MYSQLi or PDO instead. An example of this would be:

```
$connection= mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "database")
or die(mysqli_error("error connecting to database"));
```