# #2002 - No connection could be made

Tags: mysql

MySQL said: Documentation

## 2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).
help me to solve this...

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_connect(): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21987746/mysql-connect-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively)

Comment: Did the answer make some sense to you!!?

Answer (score 0):

This can occur when connecting using HTTP-tunneling to a MySQL server running on Unix/Linux platforms.

If the directory /var/lib/mysql doesn't exist than create it and chown to user mysql:

```
"mkdir /var/lib/mysql; chown mysql /var/lib/mysql"
```

Then edit the /etc/my.cnf file and specify

```
[mysqld]
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.socket
[client]
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.socket
```

and restart the mysql server ("**etc/init.d/mysql restart**")

That is enough for MysSQL. However the chances are that php was compiled with a different default mysql socket location (e.g. **/tmp/mysql.sock**). In which case you have to edit the php.ini file and find the variable "mysql.default_socket". Set this to the above value

```
mysql.default_socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.socket
```

and restart Apache to re-read the php.ini file.