# Connecting to a remote MYSQL server using PDO, results in same error SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

OK I have researched every step and done as much as I could and still get the following error:

```
Error!: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because 
the target machine actively refused it.
```

(BTW this solution, [PHP Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29395452/php-connection-failed-sqlstatehy000-2002-connection-refused), does not relate, my problem refers to a connection to a remote mysql server, not a virtual machine, and changing to port 8888 or port 8889 has no effect on the message..)

### Here is what I did:

1. I have created a remote connection in mysql:
   `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON fin_sample.* to fin_test@'%' identified by '****';`
2. I have changed `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysql.cnf`
3. Confirmed I stopped and restarted mysql.

At this point the server should be accepting remote connections.  Here is my code:

```
    try {
        $user = 'fin_test';
        $pass = '****';
        // Note "recommended" space after colon..
        $dbh = new PDO('mysql: host=67.205.123.123;dbname=fin_test', $user, $pass);
        foreach($dbh->query('SELECT * FROM fin_test.progview_sample') as $row) {
            print_r($row);
        }
        $dbh = null;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
        die();
    }
```

I am wondering how I debug this, or what is going wrong? I get the same response regardless of what input I use.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29395452/php-connection-failed-sqlstatehy000-2002-connection-refused

Comment: Eliminate that "recommended" space, remove ".com" from connection host, remove all fetching codes (for now) and try again. Anything?

Comment: See enapupe's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21987746/mysql-connect-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively).

Comment: removing the space and the ".com" (switching to an IP address, which I had at one point as I tried a gazillion permutations) did work @aendeerei - I do not know what you mean by "fetching code" - I can say that the only param I seem to really need is hostname=IP_address.

Comment: Yes, as in the "take the car to the mechanic and it works" - I've edited my post.

Comment: check the firewall settings on the target server?

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

I was able to solve the below by doing the following:

- removing all parameters except for `hostname=..`
- in addition I had a stupid error of `.com` after the IP address. *Warning*!! PDO is not going to tell you you are connecting to the wrong place!
- making `hostname` be an IP address

I do feel it's important to understand that you must modify the bind-address and restart mysql for the database you want to call.